# Deleting data from a table in Custom Action written in c# in wix

Tags: c#, database, wix, windows-installer, sql-delete

I have created a function that i call custom action written in c# in wix.
Inside that function i have a table into which i insert values and then populate them into the ListBox.
What i want to do is that i want to Delete all the data of that table after i call that function once.
Is there any way to delete the data.
I have done this:-

```
public static void Populate(Session session) {
        Database db = session.Database;
        string sql = db.Tables["ListBox"].SqlInsertString + " 
TEMPORARY";
        Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.View view = 
db.OpenView(sql);
            view.Execute(new Record(new Object[] {"PROPERTYASSOCIATEDWITHLISTBOX", 
1, "1", ANYTEXT"}));
        }

        view.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see page 6 of this article:

http://resources.flexerasoftware.com/web/pdf/archive/msiaccess.pdf

I apologize for not translating the VBScript into C#.  I'm a bit under the weather at the moment.